# Static website I am hosting cannot be reached and the server IP cannot be found

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, google-cloud-platform, web-hosting, google-domains

I recently used Google Domains to register a domain and have connected it to Google Cloud Console to manage a static website. I followed the [Google Codelabs guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-webapp-hosting-gcs/index.html#5) to set it up and faced no issues. However, when refreshing my website, it still doesn't load and my browser (Chrome) gives me the following error message:

> **This site can’t be reached**
>
> carbonfootprint.dev’s server IP address could not be found."

As well, going to `www.carbonfootprint.dev` gives me another error message:

> **Your connection is not private**
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.carbonfootprint.dev (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

...Which is confusing, because I was under the impression that a `.dev` domain suffix gives SSL certification by default.

However, in my Google Domains settings, **the website content appears as it should** in the minimized preview that exists in both the *Domain Overview* panel and *Website* panel. It has been over 48 hours, so it should have updated by now if it were just a delay issue.

For reference, [this is what my Custom resource records look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ZmH.png), and [these are my bucket details in Google Cloud Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKCGH.png). If it matters, I am also using a Mac.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: A `.dev` domain _requires_ a TLS certificate, it does not _include_ one. A registrar might offer you a free certificate, but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS lookup is working.
The certificate for this website doesn't have an SAN for the URL/Hostname.

The post below may have had a similar issue. Worth checking ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759710/setting-up-ssl-for-google-cloud-storage-static-website

Comment: This was very helpful, I ended up switching to Firebase for ease of use, as it automatically upgrades connections to https. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You SSL certificate lacks SAN as the IshRaj said. At least a few hours ago when I checked.

> The Subject Alternative Name field lets you specify additional host names (sites, IP addresses, common names, etc.) to be protected by a single SSL Certificate, such as a Multi-Domain (SAN) or Extend Validation Multi-Domain Certificate.[[1]](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm) [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name)

Right now there's no IP being resolved under this name;

```
:~$ dig cname www.carbonfootprint.dev +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> cname www.carbonfootprint.dev +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
```

**GCP is designed to serve static websites only over HTTP using custom domain name** (you can you direct links though but it's far from perfect) - you have to create a Load Balancer. All the steps how to create a static website with Load Balancer are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110824/ssl-for-static-websites-in-google-cloud). And here's some [google documentation on serving sites over HTTPS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https).

Answer (score 0):

Check once the status of your SSL certificate . Whether root and intermediate SSL certificate and linked and installed properly or not check with you url in" SSL checker" website
And futher check in your web server whether your are application is accessible within server if yes . Further check with network engineer whether traffic is seen or dns is getting resolving when your are intiating traffic